# I want to add one table on the last facet of the ggplot graphic, but the tables show up one every facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I made a `ggplot` graphic which had 5 facets using `facet_wrap`.

The sixth is blank, I want to add a table.

```
ggplot(data = ccdataff, aes(x = 处理, y = mean, color=处理)) +theme_bw()+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position =  "dodge",fill="white")+facet_wrap(~植物)
```

[image: plot 1]

[image: plot 2]

Comment: Plot each facet as a separate plot in a list, and one plot with table (probably some grid package), then use `cowplot::plot_grid` to put all together. Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), and show your existing code.

Comment: I've answered a similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496764/add-textbox-to-facet-wrapped-layout-in-ggplot2/46150040#46150040), with a solution that involved converting the facetted ggplot object into a grob. Would it be relevant for your use case?

Comment: Agree with other posters that you will need to use an additional package like `cowplot` or `gridExtra` to do this

Comment: yes,thank you all,ggplot is not enough ,need grid