# R: Reliable conversion between gtable and ggplot objects. How to make lemon::reposition_legend() work after ggplot_build()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, facet, r-lemon

I have a pretty complicated case at hand with `ggplot2`. I tried to exemplify it with a MWE using `iris` data below.

I just have boxplots in facets, and wanted to move the legend to take the space of the empty facets.

This is all good, I use `lemon::reposition_legend()` for that and it works.

However, I then have to modify a bunch of things in the plot (namely add significant test results and other things that are not relevant for this question), and I am forced to use `ggplot_build()` on my output plot for that purpose.

After using `ggplot_build()` to modify my plot, I do not seem to be able to use `reposition_legend()` successfully anymore...

Check out my MWE below.

First I load the packages I need, and define a `shift_legend()` function (which uses `reposition_legend()`), based on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438495/shift-legend-into-empty-facets-of-a-faceted-plot-in-ggplot2).

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotify)
library(gtable)
library(cowplot)
library(purrr)
library(lemon)
library(grid)
shift_legend <- function(p) {
  pnls <- NULL
  if (class(p)[1] == "gtable") pnls <- p
  else if (class(p)[2] == "ggplot") pnls <- plot_to_gtable(p)
  else stop("Please provide a ggplot or a gtable object")

  pnls <- gtable_filter(pnls, "panel")
  pnls <- setNames(pnls$grobs, pnls$layout$name)
  pnls <- keep(pnls, ~identical(.x, zeroGrob()))

  res <- NULL
  if(length(pnls) > 0) res <- reposition_legend( p, "center", panel=names(pnls) )
  else res <- p
  return(res)
}
```

I then load the `iris` data and make my plot with `shift_legend()` successfully.

```
data(iris)
summary(iris)
iris_long <- gather(iris, "Variable", "Value", -Species)
P <- ggplot(iris_long, aes(x=Variable, y=Value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Variable), position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_wrap(.~Species, ncol=2) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "inch"))
out_file_name <- "test.pdf"
pdf(file=out_file_name, height=10, width=10, onefile=FALSE)
print(
  grid.draw(shift_legend(P))
)
dev.off()
```

This produces this output, all good till here:
[image: test]
**Note this is the arrangement I want to be able to reproduce (after using `ggplot_build`), with the legend taking the empty facets space.**

But now I need to use `ggplot_build()` to add and modify things in my plot. After that I can plot it normally without using `reposition_legend()`.

```
P2 <- ggplot_build(P)
#Do a bunch of things here...
out_file_name2 <- "test2.pdf"
pdf.options(reset=TRUE, onefile=FALSE)
pdf(file=out_file_name2, height=10, width=10)
print(
  plot(ggplot_gtable(P2))
)
dev.off()
```

Which produces this:
[image: test2]

But I still want to reposition the legend, so I attempt to use `reposition_legend()` again converting the `ggplot_built` object into a `gtable` object (which, according to [the function documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lemon/versions/0.4.3/topics/reposition_legend) it can accept also as input).

```
out_file_name22 <- "test22.pdf"
pdf.options(reset=TRUE, onefile=FALSE)
pdf(file=out_file_name22, height=10, width=10)
print(
  grid.draw(shift_legend(
    ggplot_gtable(P2)
  ))
)
dev.off()
```

Here I get this error:

> Error in reposition_legend(p, "center", panel = names(pnls)) :
>   No legend given in arguments, or could not extract legend from plot.

I tried again converting the `gtable` object into a `ggplot` one using `ggplotify::as.ggplot()`. This time I obtained no errors, but the legend was not repositioned as expected...

```
out_file_name222 <- "test222.pdf"
pdf.options(reset=TRUE, onefile=FALSE)
pdf(file=out_file_name222, height=10, width=10)
print(
  grid.draw(shift_legend(
    as.ggplot(ggplot_gtable(P2))
  ))
)
dev.off()
```

It produces this:
[image: test222]

Help please!

**EDIT**

I tried to change the workflow, as suggested in the comments and answers, to no avail.

Being `P` the original plot, what I need to modify is in the `ggplot_build(P)$data` data frame.

This data frame looks like this:

```
> ggplot_build(P)$data
[[1]]
      fill ymin lower middle upper ymax           outliers notchupper notchlower x PANEL group ymin_final ymax_final  xmin  xmax weight colour size alpha shape
1  #F8766D  1.2 1.400   1.50 1.575  1.7 1.1, 1.0, 1.9, 1.9  1.5391030  1.4608970 1     1     1        1.0        1.9 0.625 1.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
2  #7CAE00  0.1 0.200   0.20 0.300  0.4           0.5, 0.6  0.2223446  0.1776554 2     1     2        0.1        0.6 1.625 2.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
3  #00BFC4  4.3 4.800   5.00 5.200  5.8                     5.0893783  4.9106217 3     1     3        4.3        5.8 2.625 3.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
4  #C77CFF  2.9 3.200   3.40 3.675  4.2           4.4, 2.3  3.5061367  3.2938633 4     1     4        2.3        4.4 3.625 4.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
5  #F8766D  3.3 4.000   4.35 4.600  5.1                  3  4.4840674  4.2159326 1     2     1        3.0        5.1 0.625 1.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
6  #7CAE00  1.0 1.200   1.30 1.500  1.8                     1.3670337  1.2329663 2     2     2        1.0        1.8 1.625 2.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
7  #00BFC4  4.9 5.600   5.90 6.300  7.0                     6.0564120  5.7435880 3     2     3        4.9        7.0 2.625 3.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
8  #C77CFF  2.0 2.525   2.80 3.000  3.4                     2.9061367  2.6938633 4     2     4        2.0        3.4 3.625 4.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
9  #F8766D  4.5 5.100   5.55 5.875  6.9                     5.7231705  5.3768295 1     3     1        4.5        6.9 0.625 1.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
10 #7CAE00  1.4 1.800   2.00 2.300  2.5                     2.1117229  1.8882771 2     3     2        1.4        2.5 1.625 2.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
11 #00BFC4  5.6 6.225   6.50 6.900  7.9                4.9  6.6508259  6.3491741 3     3     3        4.9        7.9 2.625 3.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
12 #C77CFF  2.5 2.800   3.00 3.175  3.6      3.8, 2.2, 3.8  3.0837922  2.9162078 4     3     4        2.2        3.8 3.625 4.375      1 grey20  0.5    NA    19
   linetype
1     solid
2     solid
3     solid
4     solid
5     solid
6     solid
7     solid
8     solid
9     solid
10    solid
11    solid
12    solid
```

I modify aspects of it like `annotation` (not applicable in this MWE) and `colour`.

However, if, as suggested, I attempt to shift the legend of `P` **before** using `ggplot_build()` to extract and modify the relevant info, I have to do the following:

```
P2 <- as.ggplot(shift_legend(P))
ggplot_build(P2)$data
```

The first command opens a new plotting window, which is undesired.

The second command produces this:

```
> ggplot_build(P2)$data
[[1]]
  x y PANEL group
1 0 0     1    -1
2 1 1     1    -1

[[2]]
  PANEL group xmin xmax ymin ymax
1     1    -1    0    1    0    1
```

This looks nothing like the `data` data frame I modify in `P`... Any clue where to find it, if possible, in `P2` now?

**EDIT 2**

Just so you see an example of my real life boxplots to see why modifying `ggplot_build(P)$data` is important to me.

There is no way to show only significant pairwise comparisons with `geom_signif()`.

What I do is use `geom_signif()` with dummy text to populate the annotation data frame I can access at `ggplot_build(P)$data[[3]]`, and then add my actual significance values to the `$annotation` column, and subset the data frame accordingly to show only significant comparisons. There I have full control, and can change the colors of the comparisons according to significance, which group has a higher mean, etc, etc.

I asked this a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783163/r-ggplot2-boxplots-with-wilcoxon-significance-levels-and-facets-show-only-sig), and ever since I have polished this and wrapped it into a function.

As you see, this clashes with my `shift_legend` function, as I do not seem to find a way to access the `data` data frame...

This is what I have so far with my real life data, I placed the legend at the bottom, but it would be optimal that it took the empty facets space, especially cause I have cases where there are more empty facets.

[image: real case]

Comment: can you change your workflow slightly? i.e. assign the plot with the updated legend `P2 = shift_legend(P)` and then either update the `gtable` `P2` instead of the `ggplot_build` or use `ggplot_build(as.ggplot(P2))`

Comment: Oooohhh I'm going to try that in a second... I wouldn't mind changing anything in the workflow, or using something different from `lemon` for that matter, as  long as I can get the desired result

Comment: Cannot... the result of `shift_legend` is a `gtable`, but `ggplot_build` only accepts a `ggplot` object... that's the rule of this whole problem, a reliable conversion between `gtable` and `ggplot` objects

Comment: I could do `P2 <- ggplot_build(as.ggplot(shift_legend(P))`, but then I don't have access to `P2$data[[3]] ` where is where I add all my annotations and all

Comment: besides that would open a pop-up plotting window...

Comment: Please check my EDIT. Note I used [[3]] in the comments cause it's the data frame that corresponds to the test annotations in my real life plots, but for the MWE it does not apply (just $data)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have revised this answer based on further information from the OP.

We start by loading the libraries and creating the plot. For this example I have added an extra layer of text objects that can be manipulated in the resulting `ggplot_built` object, as the OP requires:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotify)
library(gtable)
library(cowplot)
library(purrr)
library(lemon)
library(grid)

data(iris)

iris_long   <- gather(iris, "Variable", "Value", -Species)
text_labels <- data.frame(text = "Text", x = 2, y = 3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

P <- ggplot(iris_long, aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
     geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Variable), position = position_dodge(.9)) +
     geom_text(data = text_labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = text)) +
     facet_wrap(.~Species, ncol = 2) +
     theme_light() +
     theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "inch"))
```

Now we convert to the `ggplot_built` object and manipulate it as necessary. Here, we'll just manually change the colour of the text through `P2$data[[2]]`

```
# Convert to ggplot_built
P2 <- ggplot_build(P)

# Do stuff with P2$data
P2$data[[2]]$colour <- rep("red", 3)

# We have changed P2 successfully
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(P2))
```

[image]

Now we want to add the legend to the facet. We grab a copy of the legend from our plot using `ggplot_gtable`:

```r
P3 <- reposition_legend(ggplot_gtable(P2), "center", 
                        legend = g_legend(ggplot_gtable(P2)), 
                        panel = "panel-2-2")
```

However, this creates a new problem: we have our correctly placed legend, but we also have the old one that we no longer want:

[image]

We then fix this by finding the grob we don't want and overwriting it with a zerogrob:

```r
legend_grob <- which(sapply(P3$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
P3$grobs[[legend_grob]] <- zeroGrob()
```

Now, we will still have a blank space at the right side of our plot that we don't want, so we apply a negative pad to the right:

```
P3 <- gtable_add_padding(P3, unit(c(0,-.15, 0, 0), "npc")
```

Now we can plot the result with `grid.draw`:

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(P3)
```

[image]

Note that we have preserved the changes we made manually to the `ggplot_built` object.

So your function to transform a `ggplot_built` object into a plot with the legend moved to the facet would be something like:

```
legend_as_facet <- function(P2)
{
  # Convert the ggplot_built object to a gtable
  P2       <- ggplot_gtable(P2)

  # Find the name of the panel on the bottom right of the plot
  panels   <- grep("panel", P2$layout$name, value = TRUE)
  panelmat <- sapply(strsplit(panels, "-"), function(x) as.numeric(x[2:3]))
  maxpanel <- paste("panel", max(panelmat[2,]), max(panelmat[2,]), sep = "-")

  # Draw the legend in the bottom right panel
  P3 <- reposition_legend(P2, "center", legend = g_legend(P2), panel = maxpanel)

  # Draw a zero grob in place of the existing legend
  legend_grob <- which(sapply(P3$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  P3$grobs[[legend_grob]] <- zeroGrob()

  # Apply negative padding to remove the empty space on the right
  P3 <- gtable_add_padding(P3, unit(c(0,-.15, 0, 0), "npc"))

  # Draw the result
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(P3)
}
```

This means your work flow would be:

```
P2 <- ggplot_build(P)

# Do stuff with P2$data

legend_as_facet(P2)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This looks good, let me give it a try in a while! Only two things I see: 1) I would need my `shift_legend` function to work for both plots I don;t want to modify and plots I want to modify. 2) The modifications I carry out involve basically the `annotation` field in `ggplot_build(P)$data[[3]]`, is there access to that with your approach? Thanks!

Comment: I can modify my question to add a couple of dummy modifications that resemble what I do in `ggplot_build(P)$data[[3]]` (basically just add t-test significance results)

Comment: Just tried, I cannot use this approach as is, as I commented the other day... I need access to `P2$data[[3]]$annotation`, `P2$data[[3]]$colour`, etc. I can access that `data` data frame for `P`, but not for `P2` after applying the `reposition_legend` function

Comment: Check `ggplot_build(P)$data`. This is the data frame I modify, and I have nowhere to find for `P2` (after using `shift_legend`)... `P2$data` looks completely different as the expected `ggplot_build(P)$data`

Comment: Please check my EDIT. Note I used `[[3]]` in the comments cause it's the data frame that corresponds to the test annotations in my real life plots, but for the MWE it does not apply (just `$data`)

Comment: @DaniCee I have updated. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Alright, this looks more like it! Let me test in a couple hours when I have some time and get back to you, but looks good!! Thanks

Comment: Only problem I see I might face is with `panel = "panel-2-2"`... as in do I have to know in advance where to place the legend at? I do this automatically so I wouldn't know

Comment: @DaniCee is it always the bottom right panel you want? If so, you can find this programmatically ahead of the call to `reposition_legend`

Comment: @DaniCee I have changed the function so that it chooses the correct panel automatically