# Adding a custom legend and/or label in facet wrapped ggplot panel

Tags: r

I have a panel like the following. I want to add some info in the unused space, but don't know how to incorporate a custom legend or annotation into that space which I've indicated with blue:

[image]

Here's my code

```
p %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=year, y=prop1)) +
  geom_line( group=1, aes(color=group), color="black", size=1.2 )+
  geom_line(data=p %>% dplyr::select(-group), aes(group=group2), color="grey", size=0.5, alpha=0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("a panel") +
  facet_wrap(~name)+ 
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496764/add-textbox-to-facet-wrapped-layout-in-ggplot2) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450765/how-to-use-empty-space-produced-by-facet-wrap)?

Comment: I have not! That looks exactly like mine. Thanks