# How to arrange one grob object inside another with ggplot2 and gridExtra packages in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I would like to know how to arrange one grob object (a table) inside another. Consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- qplot(data=mtcars, x = mpg, y = hp, facets = ~ hp, geom="point")
t1 <- tableGrob(head(mtcars))
print(arrangeGrob(p1, t1))
```

This yields:

[image: Plot 01]

What I would like to do is place the table **inside** the other object like this:

[image: Desired Result]

Is this possible to do using `gridArrange` or perhaps some other methods from `grid` and/or `gridExtra`?

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r/12318578#12318578) may be a start. I know there are also some posts about explicitly placing 'something' in an empty panel in a facetted plot. Can't find them right now...

Comment: This is the one I was thinking of: [**How to use empty space produced by facet_wrap?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450765/how-to-use-empty-space-produced-by-facet-wrap/22451866#22451866).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility using grid functions:

```
png("SO.png", width = 1440, height = 720)

plot(p1)

vp <- viewport(x = 0.95, y = 0.02, 
               width = unit(0.4, "npc"), height = unit(0.2, "npc"),
               just = c("right", "bottom"))
pushViewport(vp)
grid.draw(t1)

dev.off()
```

[image: resulting plot]